# Strategy to handle token expiration event across all view models

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvm-light

The application architecture is: MVVM[Views -> ViewModels] -> Repositories -> API.

The API layer can throw a `TokenExpiredException` exception, which we ultimately want to handle at the UI layer (by showing a message box and redirecting to login).

Today, our VMs interact with the repositories like so:

```
SomeCommand {
    await _repo.DoSomethingAsync();
}
```

My question is on finding a good pattern to handle this exception from the API layer. I can think of 3 approaches:

**1)** Wrap every repository call in a `BaseViewModel` method that takes care of catching and handling this view model-agnostic exception.

```
SomeCommand {
    await base.RepoRequest(() => _repo.DoSomethingAsync());
}
```

where `BaseViewModel` would have:

```
RepoRequest(action) {
    try { action() }
    catch (TokenExpiredException) {
        // show message box
        // redirect
    }
```

any other exception, such as a validation error, would be handled in the VM. The problem I see here is that it's too easy to forget to use this pattern. I might call the repository directly somewhere and miss handling the exception.

**2)** Every VM catches this exception

```
SomeCommand {
    try { await _repo.DoSomethingAsync(); }
    catch (InvalidUsernameException) { ... }
    catch (TokenExpiredException) {
        // show message box
        // redirect
    }
```

Not really different from 1), same issues and requires more code duplication.

**3)** Using an event aggregator to publish a message from the API layer to the `BaseViewModel`.

```
ApiRequest {
    var response = await _httpClient.ExecuteAsync<..>(...);

    if (response.ErrorId == "InvalidUsername")
        throw new InvalidUsernameException();
    else if (response.ErrorId == "TokenExpired")
        EventAggregator.Publish(new TokenExpiredException());
}
```

and `BaseViewModel`

```
onMessage(TokenExpiredException e) {
    // show message box
    // redirect
}
```

This has the advantage of leaving all VMs (but the base) free of wiring up.
Disadvantage is that I'm hesitant to use an event aggregator 1) at all 2) at the API layer.
We are using mvvm-light and this would mean referencing those libraries in our deeper layers just for the `Messenger` (its event aggregator).

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to cleanly implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I had to figure out the same problem, but I was using WCF with the castle wcf facility, this helped me, because the facility already had [point of extension](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/tree/master/src/Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration/Client/Policies) for intercepting the calls. So I just created my custom `AbstractWcfPolicy` and intercepted all the exception that I want to manage.

With the same idea you can think about using a proxy class, based on [castle dynamic proxy](http://docs.castleproject.org/Tools.DynamicProxy-Introduction.ashx), in that way your call will remain `await _repo.DoSomethingAsync();` but under the wood your ExceptionInterceptor will intercept all the exception and do whatever you want:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class Interceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before target call");
        try
        {
           invocation.Proceed();
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Target threw an exception!");
           throw;
        }
        finally
        {
           Console.WriteLine("After target call");
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can throw back some of the exceptions you might want to throw anyway, for some of the exception or all, you could also implement a publish-subscribe (a global message broker, the [messenger in MVVM Light](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/696340/Thinking-in-MVVMLight-Messenger)) mechanism where you push the exception, and then in any point of your application you can subscribe to those errors and do something (log, show the error to the user in an unobtrusive way, etc...).

Comment: Interesting parallel to the Windsor approach. After subscribing to listen for the message in a base VM class constructor should capture when the event is fired without having to litter the app with too much redundant handling.

Comment: @IanPatrickHughes actually is all about [Aspect-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), avoid change any line of code, instead inject behaviors, and this is a case where the AOP perfectly fit, another case is for logging purpose, sometimes in wpf application, I do both, intercepting for logging exception and to manage some kind of notification back to the app. Also in WCF is really important intercept all the exception, and always avoid throwing an exception that is not a FaultException, so I intercept to log and wrap the internal exception.